# Epsilon and comparison

Tags: python

I was wondering how I can edit this code to include a calculation that will allow me to print out the power of 2 as well, so that I can write the machine epsilon as `2^(1-t)`, where `t` is the number of bits in the mantissa, and would this match the theoretical number of bits in the mantissa of a double precision (python float) number in base 2?

```
def MachineE():
    eps = 2.0**(-1)
    while eps + 1 > 1:
        eps = eps / 2.0
    print 2.0 * eps

MachineE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivial solution to the first question:

```
def MachineE():
    eps = 2.0**(-1)
    t = 2
    while eps + 1 > 1:
        eps = eps / 2.0
        t += 1
    print "2^({}) = {}".format(2-t, 2.0 * eps)

MachineE()
```

But I would recommend using `sys.float_info.epsilon` directly. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info.

```
>>> MachineE() 
2^(-52) = 2.220446049250313e-16
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.epsilon
2.220446049250313e-16
>>> import math
>>> math.log( sys.float_info.epsilon,2)
-52.0
```

Second question: short answer: yes. Very long answer to all kinds of related questions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html .